# Few primary events with a lots of secondary events

Tags: predictionio

I would like to use universal [recommender](http://templates.prediction.io/PredictionIO/template-scala-parallel-universal-recommendation) and in my case I would to use one primary event "like" and a secondary event "view".

On my website, "like" event will be send when a user will click on a like button of the UI, whereas the secondary event "view" will be send for each page view.

So It's possible that a user will not have primary events but a lots of secondary events. It is correct to do this ? All users will get recommendation is this case ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, all users who have some history, either of primary or secondary events, will get recommendations.